# Checkbox on the Shopify product page

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-api

I currently have this code, in which the 6 options for the 6 variations of products that I have in shopify are dynamically created

```
  {% for variant in product.variants %}
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{ variant.id }}" name="{{ variant.title }}" value="{{ variant.title}}">
  <label for="{{ variant.title }}"> {{ variant.title }}</label><br>
  {% endfor %}
```

Even there if you show me my options in a checkbox, what I don't get is when I add the chosen options to the cart, the cart does not take this value, but instead takes the default option which is a select that comes in shopify

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is an hidden input in your product form like this one and remove it:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.first_available_variant.id }}">
```